# Disable audio for specific users

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service, audio

I want to disable audio for specific users with GPO or something else. Our network model is not domain. So there aren't system services path in GPO. How can i do this?

Comment: Too bad you don't have an AD domain. Now it's like trying to put a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: Do you think is there any way to do that? @EsaJokinen

Comment: AD and GP are for deploying such settings in all networks that fits the scope of Serverfault (professional system administration). For home users putting the speakers in a locked cabinet could be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file mute.vbs:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(chr(173))
```

Create a NoAudio.cmd script file that is run by the user at logon:

```
cscript mute.vbs
```

The script could be based on criteria such as membership in local group that you create:

```
REM NoAudio.cmd
WHOAMI /GROUPS | FINDSTR /i "GRP-NOAUDIO"  
REM If ERRORLEVEL is 1, not in group
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 GOTO :EOF
cscript mute.vbs
```

Taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255419/how-can-i-mute-unmute-my-sound-from-powershell